# Perforce won't branch over deleted files

Tags: perforce

I'm using perforce, and I have a `../dev` folder with my code, a `../trunk` folder with the testable code, and a `../rel` folder for the code ready to be deployed to production. The way I work is that I work on `../dev`, and when I have a stable version, I branch to `../trunk`. After testing, I grab `../trunk` and branch it to `../rel`.

I accidentally branched `../dev` to `../rel`, so I went ahead and marked for delete the `../rel` folder. Then, I tried to branch `../trunk` to `../rel` but perforce is failing saying that "Can't populate target path when files already exist". So, it seems that even if I delete the files that were wrongfully on branched to `../rel`, they still exist and I can't overwrite them with the `../trunk` files.

What can I do?

Comment: It's just the **populate** command that has that restriction. The regular **integrate** command doesn't have that restriction, nor does the **copy** command. So 'p4 copy //depot/trunk/... //depot/rel/...' should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "force integration" flag:

> p4 integrate -f ../dev/... ../rel/...